# Twitter emoticons in unicode in r on windows

Tags: r, twitter, unicode, sentiment-analysis, emoticons

I am doing a sentiment analysis on twitter data and am struggling with the Unicode encoding for emoticons in the tweets. The problem is I can't identify the emoticons. When I print text with emoticons (encoded in Unicode in such format: `<U+653C>` etc.) to the console I get Chinese signs instead of the emoticon I expect from the tweet.
With the 'validUTF8(x)' function I have checked whether the text is correctly UTF8 encoded, and it returns TRUE, which indicates that the text is indeed UTF8 encoded.

An example tweet as it is loaded into R (with some simple data cleaning) is as follows:

> `" <U+653C><U+3E64><U+613C><U+3E30><U+623C><U+3E63><U+653C><U+3E64><U+623C><U+3E37><U+613C><U+3E39><U+653C><U+3E64><U+613C><U+3E30><U+623C><U+3E63><U+653C><U+3E64><U+623C><U+3E37><U+623C><U+3E30> begint op de bank tijdens de laatste groepswedstrijd van denemarken uur den fra worldcup feyenoord "`

this is how this code is displayed in the console in R:

```
[1] "攼㹤愼㸰戼㹣攼㹤戼㸷愼㸹攼㹤愼㸰戼㹣攼㹤戼㸷戼㸰   begint op de bank tijdens de laatste groepswedstrijd van denemarken        uur  den   fra   worldcup feyenoord "
```

and the link to the specific tweet is [here](https://twitter.com/Feyenoord/status/1011596769522782211). BTW: I load my twitter data into R with the rtweets package and the `search_tweets` function and am working on Windows 10.

I want to be able to identify the emoticon by matching the Unicode against the [Unicode database](http://www.unicode.org/Public/emoji/5.0/emoji-data.txt) in order to use the emoticons in my sentiment analysis. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: So how exactly did you import this tweet? Does the string literally have "<U+653C>" values in the test? How did you convert those to proper Unicode values? It would be best if you could give as close as possible to a "raw" value. Maybe using something like `charToRaw()` to see exactly what bytes are in the original string.

Comment: I imported the tweets as such:  
    `tweetsdf <- search_tweets(subject, n = 100, lang = 'nl',type = 'recent', include_rts = FALSE)  `
And if I preview the raw twitter data, it indeed has "<f0><U+009F><U+0098>" values, although if I print it to the console it shows like "\xf0\u009f\u0098".  After I use `charToRaw()` I get "f0 9f 98" for this specific code. However, I can't find these codes in the [Unicode emoji data](http://www.unicode.org/Public/emoji/5.0/emoji-data.txt).

Comment: Those are different numbers than you have above. Is that a different tweet?

Comment: Yes indeed! I have now searched for another subject in the `search_tweets` function.